# Mvvm light issue, not updating UI / buttonstates correctly

Tags: c#, mvvm

We have a strange issue with MVVM light. Our application has some buttons which perform tasks like starting a socketlisterner via a task:

```
 Task.Run(() => { _serviceMonitor.SocketServer.StartListening(); });
```

The RelayCommands are setup to use CanExecute options:

```
 public RelayCommand StartSocketServerCommand => _startSocketServerCommand ?? (_startSocketServerCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteStartSocketServerCommand, CanStartSocketServerCommand));
```

For unclear reasons, the UI does not always update the button state (enable/disable) correctly until we just click somewhere on the UI. Then the buttons states are correctly enabled/disabled.

Does this sounds familiar to anyone?